# Trying to get Strings to print in a new file

Tags: java

I've been trying to learn Java and I've done a few courses and picked up bits and pieces everywhere. I'm now trying to find small projects which could be applicable to my work and I am stuck on the latest one.

I have one CSV file filled with rows of data. I have another template apt file opened in text. I need to replace the placeholder text in the template file (apt file) with specific data from each row in the data file and then save the edited apt file as a new file and repeat for each row in the data file until the end.

I've gotten as far as reading the two files, replacing the placeholder data and creating a new file and I'm able to get the correct output in System.out.println but I'm struggling to get the Filewriter and BufferredWriter to write the edited text into my newly created file. I'm now out of ideas.

```
package com.company;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File data = new File("Scheduler.csv");
        Scanner dataScanner = new Scanner(data);
        

            String dataLine = dataScanner.nextLine();
            String[] HUDetail = dataLine.split(",");
            //System.out.println(dataLine);

            String BAU = HUDetail[0];
            String forest = HUDetail[1];
            String HUNumber = HUDetail[2];
            String hType = HUDetail[3];
            String contractCode = HUDetail[4];
            String contractor = HUDetail[5];

            String editBAU = "AAAA";
            String editForest = "BBBB";
            String editHUNumber = "CCCC";
            String editHType = "DDDD";
            String editContractCode = "EEEE";
            String editContractor = "FFFF";

        File apt = new File("Aptuary_file.txt");
        Scanner aptScanner = new Scanner(apt);

        File newApt = new File("HUNumber +".apt");
        try {
            newApt.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Filecreator error");}

        try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(HUNumber + ".apt"))) {
            //System.out.println(HUNumber);

            while(aptScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String aptLine = aptScanner.nextLine();
                //System.out.println(aptLine);
                String HUNumberApt = aptLine.replaceAll(editBAU, BAU)
                        .replaceAll(editForest, forest)
                        .replaceAll(editHUNumber, HUNumber)
                        .replaceAll(editHType, hType)
                        .replaceAll(editContractCode, contractCode)
                        .replaceAll(editContractor, contractor);
                out.write(HUNumberApt);


                System.out.println(HUNumberApt);
            }
            }catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Filewriter error");}
    }
    }
```

Comment: I can help you with this. Please provide example input data and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on this Line:

```java
File newApt = new File("HUNumber +".apt");
```

it should be

```java
File newApt = new File(HUNumber +".apt");
```

On this one:

```java
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(HUNumber + ".apt")))
```

you can pass the file as parameter

```java
try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(newApt))
```

Comment: Thanks a million, the changes you recommended worked perfectly. I can push on now!

Comment: Hi @user73090 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.